# href=tel:123 not working on ipod touch ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I would like to call a number in my app:

I know that `tel:+1378987398` works on an iPod touch since there is Facetime. Mailto works and weblinks as well. I've installed the inapp browser. But when i use

```
$scope.goTo = function(url) {
     window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
  }
```

And in html

```
ng-click="goTo('tel:+136786387')"
```

Also no effect.

What's my mistake?

This is the code:

config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
  <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="true" />
  <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="true" />
```

And in index.html:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">
```

The href:

```
<a href="tel:+397856001078">+39 7856001078</a>
```

It works in the browser..

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe just trigger a click on the link via script …?

Comment: Like I did with ng-click? @CBroe

Comment: No, I mean actually _trigger_ a click event.